# Spring Boot white label error page after deployed on Railway

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, web-deployment

I deployed this Spring Boot [application](https://github.com/Adoration4None/Unicine) on Railway, but after the deploy is finished and with no errors, when I access the provided link https://unicine.up.railway.app, it only shows the White Label Error Page.

[This is the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiwnW.png) (**negocio** is the "backend" module and **web** is the "frontend" module).
When the application is launched on *localhost* it shows the **index.xhtml** page by default, and I can navigate to other pages like **login_admin.xhtml** by typing it in the URL, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1q80.png), but when I try to do the same in the deployed Railway app, the error page keeps coming up.

I know the app is being deployed and started correctly, the problem seems to be that it doesn't find the files to show when entering the page.

I have this class in *unicine/web/src/main/java/co.edu.uniquindio.unicine/config/* that sets the start page:

```
package co.edu.uniquindio.unicine.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class PaginaPrincipalConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.xhtml");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

And it's working fine when runned on localhost, but it seems like it's not working when deployed on Railway.

How could I fix that? Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. My cause was that the request failed to resolve because an exception was thrown, hence no reaction from pinging "/". Are you maybe trying to load files from the resource folder?

Comment: I'm having an issue when reading files from resource folders, I'm reading the files with ClassPathResource but it fails